# What is the fastest deterministic primality test for numbers in the range 2^1024 to 2^4096?

Tags: algorithm, performance, primes

I am writing an implementation of a cryptography protocol.  So far I've been having a difficult time finding the fastest deterministic primality test for 1024-bit to 4096-bit integers (308- to 1233-digit numbers).  I am aware of several options but I have not been able to find real world speed comparisons.

Specifically, how does the AKS test perform compared to the deterministic version of Rabin-Miller and the Elliptic Curve Primality Proving test (and others) for general random numbers this size ?

Comment: This is an interesting post : 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33304/mareys-problem-generating-all-prime-numbers-in-n-1-n-2

Comment: You don't need deterministic primality tests for public key crypto - existing solutions don't use them. Almost-certainly-primes are generally sufficient. Of course, you probably shouldn't be implementing your own crypto primitives anyway, if you can avoid it.

Comment: AKS will be _very much worse_ than ECPP, which will be _very much worse_ than Miller Rabin. Note that Miller Rabin can make errors but the others can't. For crypto, Miller Rabin is generally sufficient.

Comment: Your computer has a finite (though small) chance of failing and giving an incorrect answer.  As long as the probability of a non-deterministic algorithm failing and giving the wrong answer is smaller than the chance of your hardware giving the wrong answer, then a non-deterministic answer will be fine.  Bruce Schneier calls them "industrial strength primes".  the chance of them not being prime is small enough to ignore for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This article is answering your question:

PRIMALITY TESTING by Richard P. Brent:
http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp4600/lectures/comp4600_primality.pdf

It compares in complexity and in "real world speed" the 3 algorithms.

Comment: +1 Awesome. It leaves me curious about Las Vegas algorithms. It seems preferable to have a certificate in probably-good time, than to have a probable prime in guaranteed time.

Comment: There's just one thing I still don't know: how do they compare to the _deterministic_ version of Rabin-Miller?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110414142105/http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp4600/lectures/comp4600_primality.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I'm new, so i can't comment on the above link, but here is the internet archive link to that article:

https://web.archive.org/web/20110414142105/http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp4600/lectures/comp4600_primality.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The fastest proof methods for this size would be APR-CL (e.g. [mpz_aprcl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpzaprcl/)) and ECPP (e.g. [Primo](http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html) or [ecpp-dj](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=380991&postcount=30)).  APR-CL is deterministic and almost polynomial time, while ECPP is randomized but the answer returned is proven, not probabilistic.  Alternately, use a constructive method for proven primes such as Maurer's methods or Shawe-Taylor.  These are methods for quickly generating random n-bit primes created by building up Pocklington-style proofs.  From a practical point of view, if you are generating the random candidates rather than receiving them from a third party then the error rates for Miller-Rabin are extraordinarily low, and almost all people in this case are satisfied with multiple Miller-Rabin tests using random bases, possibly with a strong Lucas test in addition.  See FIPS 186-4 for lots of info on constructive methods and recommendations for probable prime testing.

Times are shown in [this graph](http://probableprime.org/images/primality-times.png) for a selection of random n-digit primes run through trial division, BPSW (an efficient probable prime test), two versions of AKS, APR-CL, and ECPP.  This shows how AKS compares to the other methods.

I didn't add deterministic M-R as I assume you're not talking about 64-bit inputs, and over that you have to either test n/4 bases or prove the Riemann Hypothesis so you only have to test 2*log^2(n) bases.  Neither one is attractive compared to our other options even if you use the latter without a proof.  In practice the Bach version is faster than AKS as expected, but noticeably slower than ECPP and APR-CL in my tests with C+GMP.  I haven't looked at asymptotics, but at 300 digits it is over 100x slower.  Hence I don't see any point vs. APR-CL (Det M-R is slower) or ECPP (Det M-R is slower and ECPP gives you a certificate to boot).

Brent's paper can be found in this [UMS10 version from 2010](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/UMS10t4.pdf) as well as [a similar version from 2006](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/primality4.pdf).  It basically agrees with what I've found from more modern implementations in C+GMP of the various algorithms.  AKS is a landmark theoretical result, but is of no current practical use.